# Ignore spans generated by Spring PubSub

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

I'm using Spring Sleuth starter for a Spring Boot application for tracing calls from external sources. At the same time, the application has a dependency on Spring GCP Starter PubSub for handling events from other services. I checked the last spans generated by the application and found spans from `pubsubsubscriberthreadpool` (screenshot attached).

An interesting thing here is that I couldn't disable sending spans to Zipkin by adding settings to `application.yaml`. The settings are:

```
spring
  zipkin:
    base-url: http://localhost:9411
    service:
      name: notes-api
  sleuth:
    span-filter:
      additional-span-name-patterns-to-ignore: pubsubsubscriberthreadpool
      enabled: true
```

Adding a regexp-like name for the filter (`^pubsubsubscriberthreadpool$`) didn't help too.

Are there any solutions to disable such behavior?

[image: spans generated by pubsub's threadpool]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was confused about the span's name because it was not easy to find a source for it. After some research, I found a configuration bean `GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration` which registers a thread pool for PubSub. And an original name of the thread pool is `pubsubSubscriberThreadPool`. So in my case, I had to ignore the name of the span considering camelCase.

The workaround for my case is as follows:

```
spring:
  sleuth:
    span-filter:
      additional-span-name-patterns-to-ignore: ^pubsubSubscriberThreadPool$
      enabled: true
```